# webkitdirectory upload in headless Capybara test

Tags: capybara, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have a file upload control in my UI marked with webkitdirectory. When I upload a folder in the following way, running in non-headless mode, it works:

```
find('.directory-upload', visible: false).set(Rails.root + "test/data/directory_to_upload")
```

However, when I run headless (with the :headless_chromium driver) it fails silently, i.e. the code runs but the directory isn't actually selected in the control (so the ensuing form validation fails).

Are there differences in supported HTML between headless and non-headless that could explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a known bug in headless Chrome - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2521&q=directory%20upload&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary - nothing your can really do about it.